# How to define if the servlet request is initial?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to find out if my servlet request is the first one (when getting the page at the first time).

I can write the Filter to intercept all requests (even the initial one), but how reliable this approach?

```
class MyFilter implements Filter {

    private AtomicBoolean isFirstRequest = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (isFirstRequest.get()) {
            isFirstRequest.set(false);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "first one"?

Comment: First one ever or first time for this user?  Why is this necessary?  Shouldn't be - HTTP is idempotent.

Comment: I mean when getting the page at the first time.

Comment: @duffymo first one for the user.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want/need to execute some work when the application has been deployed then it will be better to use a listener like `ServletContextListener` rather than doing this work in a servlet or a filter.

Comment: I want to check Cookies.

Comment: How do you identify unique users?

Comment: I want to put a secret token in the cookies (from my domain), add this token should be also in the request header, then I check both tokens on the server. If they match then user has access to the site.

Answer (score -1):

Can't use init method of servlet?